# md5 cannot decode bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5, url-encoding, hashlib

I am trying to call a service in `python3` using `hashlib` library. The last line in this code throws the exception:

```
auth = hashed.digest().decode("utf-8").rstrip('\n')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update("".encode("utf-8"))
data_hash = base64.b64encode(m.digest()).decode("utf-8")

# Create Authorization Header
canonical = '%s,application/vnd.api+json,%s,%s,%s' % (action, data_hash, url, format_date_time(stamp))
canonical = canonical.encode("utf-8")

hashed = hmac.new(bytearray(secret, "utf-8"), canonical, sha1)
auth = hashed.digest().decode("utf-8").rstrip('\n')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you expect the digest to be UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: ...or phrased differently, what makes you expect the digest to be UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score -1):

`hashed.digest().decode("utf-8").rstrip('\n')`

Digest returns bytes but not any byte sequence is valid UTF-8.

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but this code is flawed.